# DNSMasq wildcard top level domain/suffix

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, router, dnsmasq, block

I'm running DD-WRT on my router and I need to block certain websites and all their potential suffixes, is that possible or would I have to list them all out individually?

What I have is this

```
address=/blockedomain.com/127.0.0.1
```

And then subsequent entries for all the main suffixes

Cheers.

Comment: Did you mean prefixes? If so, that one line should be enough.

Comment: No, suffix. As in .com .org .co.uk etc..

Answer (score 1):

You would need regex matching for domains to accomplish that, and [out of the box DNSMasq doesn't support it](http://www.mail-archive.com/dnsmasq-discuss@lists.thekelleys.org.uk/msg03523.html). It seems there is [unofficial patch](http://lists.thekelleys.org.uk/pipermail/dnsmasq-discuss/2012q1/005615.html) though (dunno if applicable to DD-WRT).

Answer (score 1):

I use this list https://github.com/notracking/hosts-blocklists .
In `dnnsmasq.blacklist.txt` you can add your own blacklisted *websites*, but you have to forbid your firewall to use external *DNS servers*.