# dnsmasq: How to set alias domain / multiple DNS suffixes for local hostname resolution?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, dhcp, internal-dns, dnsmasq

Is it possible to set multiple search domains via dnsmasq/DHCP? Due to some migration, I need multiple clients to be able to:

```
ping server.old-domain
ping server.new-domain
# both should work, .old-domain being an alias for .new-domain
```

I have tried the following:

- `dhcp-option=option:domain-search` - [only works for dhcpcd](https://lists.thekelleys.org.uk/pipermail/dnsmasq-discuss/2005q2/000231.html), which I cannot solely rely on
- [same link](https://lists.thekelleys.org.uk/pipermail/dnsmasq-discuss/2005q2/000231.html) also suggests `dhcp-option=15,".old-domain .new-domain"` (note the space) - seems rather to be a hack
- [regex domain pattern](https://serverfault.com/questions/546049/dnsmasq-wildcard-top-level-domain-suffix) (is this by now possible?) - didn't work for me
- setting `domain=old-domain,new-domain` in `/etc/dnsmasq` lead to syntax error with `dnsmasq --test`
- if multiple [`domain`](https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) entries, the last read is taken
- [`cname`](https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) seems to be rather for single host names, imo no wildcard possible

There are multiple scripts using the old domain name, hence a domain alias would ease up gradual migration. Have I forgotten an alternative or isn't this  possible?

`/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
domain-needed
bogus-priv
local=/new-domain/
bind-interfaces
expand-hosts
domain=new-domain
dhcp-range=...
dhcp-option=option:router,...
dhcp-option=option:dns-server,...
dhcp-leasefile=/var/lib/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.leases
dhcp-authoritative
```